# Application.js Asset Not Found in Rails Tutorial Sample App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First post here. Please be gentle. :)

I'm using the latest Rails (6-something). I'm working through Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial using both the book and the online version.

Everything has been okay until chapter 8 (p. 361 of the book) where it says to update app/assets/javascripts/application.js

I believe I can't find this file because Rails is now handling this with Webpacker. So I see this in app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

The Tutorial wants the application.js file to look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Do I convert the (outdated?) Tutorial file into code like that shown in the Webpacker file and add it to the file that already exists? Or does this get handled some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, you are only missing bootstrap in app/javascript/packs/application.js

To add bootstrap with webpacker you need to add it first with yarn:
`yarn add bootstrap@4.3.1 jquery popper.js`

Then adjust app/config/webpack/environment.js to the following:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

Now the last step is to import bootstrap in app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
```

Comment: I thought I already had bootstrap activated because the Tutorial refers to it elsewhere (earlier), and I had no problems with it being missing at those points.

Could bootstrap be implemented in my app elsewhere (especially for CSS purposes) and just not in this location for JS?

Comment: So you only need the JS part right? In that case you can skip the css part from my answer(I updated it). You need to install it with yarn or npm so it will be added to your package.json file else webpacker can't handle it and webpacker handles you JS.

Comment: Thanks for the update. After further research elsewhere online, I had figured out that what you have left above is all I needed. I also figured out that I didn't actually have bootstrap itself installed, so this now makes total sense.